# Xamarin.UITest Backdoor with Splash Screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have an application that I'm attempting to put Xamarin UI Tests on. I need to Backdoor the app to bypass my login process. 
My Backdoor method fires just fine.

```
[Activity(Label = "AppName", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }

    [Java.Interop.Export("BackDoor")] 
    public void BackDoor()
    {
        var myActivity = {Magic code to get reference to the the instance of MainActivity goes here} 


    }

}
```

However its firing in my Splash screen and I need it get a reference to my actual MainActivity not my SplashActivity. How do I get a reference to the MainActivity in my BackDoor method?

Xamarin Backdoor Docs:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/testcloud/start-activity-with-backdoor/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

Comment: According to the guide for a backdoor method for Android, it can not return `object` type, only string, Java.Lang.String, or void. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/ . Don't you want to start the next Activity from the backdoor? If so, just follow the guide you linked more closely.

Comment: nevermind, made comment answer

Comment: Its actually an Xamarin Forms app. I have to get the MainActivity that launches after the Splash screen to get the reference to the Xamarin.Application to get a reference to Navigation stack to pop the login.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just automate the login, IOW enter the user info and actually log in?

Comment: Far as I can tell I cant address componets inside a webview with Xamarin.UI.Tests. I think in the end Im just going to have to create a seperate launcher app that doesnt have a splash screen and automatically bypasses the login. But then I wont actually be testing my app. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How To Retrieve Current Activity

To retrieve the `MainActivity`, you can use [@JamesMontemagno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085228/jamesmontemagno)'s CurrentActivityPlugin.

Add the [Current Activity NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/) into your Xamarin.Android project, and then, in your Xamarin.Android Project, you can use the following line of code to retrieve the current activity and check that it is the MainActivity.

```
Activity currentActivity = Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as MainActivity;

if (!(currentActivity is MainActivity))
    throw new System.Exception("Current Activity is not MainActivity");
```

This plugin is [open-sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin).

Comment: Hope at last. Ill give it a shot and update accordingly thanks

Comment: Haha, you're welcome, @David! Good luck and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi @David! Did this solution solve your question? If so, let's mark it as answered to help future developers with the same question!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to get back to this issue as yet so havent verified it but it sure looks good

Answer (score 2):

According to the guide for a backdoor method for Android, it can not return `object` type, only `string`, `Java.Lang.String`, or `void`. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

Don't you want to start the next Activity from the backdoor as in the guide? If so, just follow the guide you linked more closely.

Also, just double checked and returning `object` from the `BackDoor` method fails on build with a NullReferenceException. However, for "{Magic code to get reference to the the instance of MainActivity goes here}" you can do:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
var myActivity = am.GetRunningTasks(1)[0].TopActivity;
```

the `myActivity` will be a reference to the top most activity, but you can't return it from the BackDoor method anyway. You can return a string description of course. I do not know why you need a reference to the activity in your test code anyway as there is not much you can do with it in the test code.

Comment: Yaeh that example is a hacked up version version of my app for the point of demo. I figured someone would comment on the return type and probably should have taken more time to clean it up. Cleaned it up now to prevent someone from cut and pasting it and cussing me out.

Comment: Looks like this doesnt actually give me a ref to the Activity it gives a ref to the ComponetName.